# Hyrule Warriors Location of Twilight princess Castle Gone?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

Hyrule Warriors has a level called Twilight Field from The Twilight Princess Era of Zelda yet twilight princess's castle has completely disappeared

Is there a canon reason why the castle is completely gone?

The bridge is in the correct position and kakariko village is almost correct

But where did the castle go?

Did cia make it disappear somehow when midna was fighting her before hyrule warriors lana, link, impa and zelda came to that era

I cant find a actual picture of in game play to show you but heres a map

Right next to that big square in the middle should be twilight princess hyrule castle
But in hyrule warriors its completely gone

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSP3bPdVEMBSLC22Nh6LvODsLmxdxiT_Qsi2Q&usqp=CAU

Where did Twilight Princess Hyrule Castle go?